# In an android app, can I just use the application context instead of a service service?

Tags: android, service, this, android-context

I made an app that uses the application context to share data and run functions between activities (or when the activity is closed). I also have a `BroadcastReceiver` that processes intents, plus it spawns new threads to run common functions stored in the App Context. Since all the activities and the Broadcast receiver can access the App Context by calling `this.getApplicationContext()`, it seems to be a much easier way to run stuff in the background while sharing data and functions throughout the app.

But I have a few questions:
Is there a downside to doing it this way? 
Why would I want to create a service if this works flawlessly? (and so far, it has)
Is there a larger battery drain doing it this way vs. the service?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no right answer. If the BroadcastReceiver mechanism is working fine, then go with it. There is no need for a Service. It is better to have a BroadcastReceiver than to have a Service which may be idle for a long time waiting upon some event/action. My 2 cents.

Comment: Actually, one has nothing to to with the other -- you have to have the BroadcastReceiver to process the intents anyway. The question is about using the Application context instead of the service